# Error building iOS application on Circle ci

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, circleci

After updating flutter to null safety I'm getting the following error on circle ci

```
▸ Copying /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dizhjshgygboszhjrotujwowqbye/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/staging/BuildProductsPath/Release-staging-iphoneos/NotificationExtension.appex
▸ Touching Runner.app (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[11:21:23]: Exit status: 65
[11:21:23]: 
[11:21:23]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[11:21:23]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[11:21:23]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[11:21:23]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode-13.0.app'
[11:21:23]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[11:21:23]: 
[11:21:23]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[11:21:23]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[11:21:23]: 
[11:21:23]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[11:21:23]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[11:21:23]: 
[11:21:23]: - Manually update the path using
[11:21:23]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

specifying Xcode doesn't help. Project builds OK when launching local from Xcode or running fastlane local

Comment: hi @Yurii did you found any solution for this issue

Comment: @Dulanga. It was weird issue. As I mentioned project was building from Xcode. What was the problem is that we had one error in code, and after fixing it, everything builded successfully. It was weird because CI didn't point on that error. Sorry but I can't find the fix now